# Disable radio-button in WinForms but show text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

Is it possible to disable radio buttons in WinForms, but to still show text of that radio button on screen?

When I do something like this:

```
rbGP.Enabled = false;
```

Text value of that radio button disappears totally.

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is to disable radio button so user cannot click on it and change its value, but still keep value of text on screen.
Does anybody know a clean way to do this?

Comment: If you are forcing to do it.. there is a Simple way.. Use Label Controls. Done

Comment: [Make WinForm readonly RadioButton look like standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39203813/3110834)

Comment: Or simple change color of background to some other tone of gray

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is because the backcolor of container is the same of the system foregroundcolor of disabled controls.

You can handle OnPaint event and redraw manually the string 
or you can just set

```
 rbGP.AutoCheck = false;
```

instead of disabling it...