# Enable=False and Don't Blur

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there any way to change the design of controls (datepicker, combo, radio) to `Enable=False` and Don't Blur? Because these controls don't have `IsReadonly` Property.

Comment: [Read-only `RadioButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212034/3110834). For `ComboBox` and `DatePicker` while you most likely can make them read-only by handling a few messages, but an easier approach would be replacing them with a read-only `TextBox`.

Comment: I strongly recommend not going down that road. A `TextBox` can be made read-only so that you can still scroll it and copy text but that's not relevant to the other controls and removing the visual cue that a control is disabled is very poor UI design.

Comment: If you really must then one option is to not use a control at all but rather just draw a visual representation of one.  The `ControlPaint` class can do that and there are individual classes per control too, e.g. `ComboBoxRenderer`.  I haven't checked but I suspect that `ControlPaint` uses those classes.